# Disable/enable NSMenu item

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I've created a menu bar app, a NSMenu object using the Interface Builder  (following [this](http://footle.org/WeatherBar/) tutorial). The menu has two items:

Start Commando

Stop Commando

How can I disable/enable the menu items when they're clicked? I've set disabled "Auto Enables Items" and I can manually enable/disable the items in the Attributes inspector, but how can I achieve the same thing when their functions are called?

When "Start Commando" is clicked I want the item to disable and "Stop Commando" to enable. And the other way around when "Stop Commando" is clicked.

Comment: Swift provides with setEnabled property that can be used on NSMenuItem you are trying to enable or disable

Comment: @MukulMore Thanks! `@IBOutlet weak var startMenuItem: NSMenuItem!` and `startMenuItem.isEnabled = false/true` did the trick.

Comment: Adding that as an answer. Mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift provides with **setEnabled** property that can be used on NSMenuItem you are trying to enable or disable.

You can do the following :

```
@IBOutlet weak var startMenuItem: NSMenuItem! 

startMenuItem.isEnabled = false or true
```

Comment: Hi, where does someone put this? Into ContentView.swift or AppDelegate.swift?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code :

```
let menu = NSMenu();
menu.autoenablesItems = false
```

Answer (score 1):

As others say, there is a `isEnabled` property for `NSMenuItem`s. One also needs to uncheck `Auto Enables Items` for that menu or sub-menu in the Attributes Inspector in Xcode, or through code, to allow the setting to take effect.

[image]

To get it to change on selection, in the `IBAction` called for the menu item, likely in your `NSWindowController`, do something like this:

```
@IBAction private func myMenuAction(sender: NSMenuItem) {
     sender.isEnabled = false 
}
```

You will not be able to then select the menu item afterwards. I assume you re-enable it else where as so:

```
if let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.myMenuItem.isEnabled = true
}
```

Code untested.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a BOOL value for instance

```
BOOL isActive 

if(isActive)
{
   //show menu
}
else
{
   //hide your menu
}
```

also make BOOL true when your view dismiss